# Проблема с чтение бинарного файла

Tags: java, binary

Пытаюсь считать бинарный файл, получаю байтовый массив.

```java
try {
    File file = new File(path + fileName);

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    int i;
    while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }

    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Что я могу сделать с этим массивом байтов и как мне перевести это в строки или символы, при кодировки файла стоит ANSI кодировка, что является по сути адаптивной кодировкой и не подходит не под одну, если я поставлю `char`, то будут вылезать сплошные кракозябры.
Сам файл состоит из вот таких вот тегов:

```
0x42525344
 Header section – must be the first section within the file.
 
0x44495247
 Grid section – describes a 2D matrix of Z values.
 
0x41544144
 Data section – contains a variable amount of data. The size of the data section is given by the Size field in the tag structure.
 
0x49544c46
 Fault Info section – describes the fault traces used when creating the grid.
 
И чисел long
 32 bit signed integer
 
double
 64 bit double precision floating point value
```

Если кротко, то это `surfer 7 grd binary` файл (https://surferhelp.goldensoftware.com/topics/surfer_7_grid_file_format.htm) - Ссылка на документацию к формату.

Answer (score 2):

Следует использовать специализированный поток для чтения данных [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), у которого есть методы для чтения примитивных типов [`DataInputStream::readLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLong--), [`DataInputStream::readDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readDouble--) и т.п.

И в соответствии с форматом файла нужно будет считывать соответствующие элементы (заголовок, двумерную матрицу, данные и т.д.).

```java
try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("surfer.dat")))) {
    long headerTag = dis.readLong();
    if (0x42525344 != headerTag) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Bad header tag: " + headerTag);
    }
    long headerSize = dis.readLong(); // header size
    long version = dis.readLong();    // version
    // ....
    // и т.д.
}
```