# Чтение бинарного файла при помощи DataInputStream

Tags: java, binary

Контекст вопроса: [Проблема с чтение бинарного файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1509399/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0/1509509#1509509)

Может быть кто-то направит меня на правильный ответ :)

```
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream
    (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path + fileName)));
    String header = "42525344";
    String grd = "44495247";
    String data = "41544144";

    int headerSection = Integer.parseInt(header, 16);
    int grdSection = Integer.parseInt(grd, 16);
    int dataSection = Integer.parseInt(data, 16);

    while (dis.available() > 0) {
        int read = dis.readInt();

        if (read == headerSection || read == grdSection || read == dataSection) {
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    }
    dis.close();
```

Я получается заголовки, то есть теги, перевел из шестнадцатеричной системы в десятичную, если я правильно понял, то dis.readInt(); читает в десятичной системе, но совпадений по заголовкам я все равно не нашел, то есть условие if не выполнилось.
Оставлю ссылку на для скачивания файла (надеюсь не запрещено), если вдруг кто-то хочет помочь
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fy8F9BRuI1UcDLfczZHHDx0h8C0RjkNq/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось получить такие же значения из вашего файла как из примера с сайта читая байты в порядке little-endian (`DataInputStream` читает их в big-endian).

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(fileLocation)));
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

int headerId = buffer.getInt();
int headerSize = buffer.getInt();
int version = buffer.getInt();
int gridId = buffer.getInt();
int gridLength = buffer.getInt();
buffer.position(buffer.position() + (gridLength - 8));
double gridBlankValue = buffer.getDouble();
int dataId = buffer.getInt();

System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(headerId)); //42525344
System.out.println(headerSize); //4
System.out.println(version); //2
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(gridId)); //44495247
System.out.println(gridLength); //72
System.out.println(gridBlankValue); //1.70141E38
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(dataId)); //41544144
```